# Unable to handle notification click for Pusher Beam

Tags: java, android, pusher

I received the notification but I didn't know where the notification is execute. In case of foreground,I received notification **onMessageReceived** but In case of background and terminate, I was unable to listen the notification listener.

```
    public class PusherMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // We just got a notification

        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction().equals("com.pusher.pushnotifications.OPEN_TRACKING")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("notification", "notification_center");
                intent.setAction("notification_center");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    // Create notification channel
                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.channel_name),
                            getString(R.string.description_channel_name),
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }

// Create notification
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.channel_name))
                        .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                        .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

                NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
                notificationManager.notify(remoteMessage.getMessageId().hashCode(), builder.build());

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How to navigate to custom activity while the app is in background or terminate state when user click the notification?